# Does minima dark skin work on github pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to set up a blog via Jekyll and GitHub Pages. To deploy it was not such a big deal, however, in trying to follow the steps described [here](https://github.com/jekyll/minima#skins) I only managed to make it display the dark skin locally. Is there a way to deploy it on GithubPages as well?
I installed it via

```rb
gem "minima", git: "https://github.com/jekyll/minima"
```

then added the following two lines in `_config.yml`

```rb
minima:
  skin: dark
```

[This](https://github.com/leoentersthevoid/leoentersthevoid.github.io) is the repo holding the ruby code.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to get the minima gem yourself, adding `remote_theme: jekyll/minima` to the _config.yml works for me.
More detail on what worked for me in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78095155/5874274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Chrome, and apparently the `Clear browsing data` in the last hour with `Cookies and other site data` and `Cached images and files` checked made the local updates appear live.

Answer (score 10):

i had this problem too. I learned that the software used by github pages isn’t updated often, hopefully for stability reasoning. You can check what versions they use at https://pages.github.com/versions/. The newer version of minima has the alternative “skins” sass/css feature, but the one currently on github pages doesn’t—-heck, github pages still hasn’t updated Jekyll to v4!!... You should be able to see the build error by clicking `Actions` on the github repo, then clicking on the last “workflow”, then click on the red-colored `build`. It’ll say the key in the config file doesn’t exist or somethin’ like that, on the `skin: dark` line.

anyway, in the config file, add `remote_theme: jekyll/minima` to force download the latest version from the github repo upon rebuild. Don’t use ~`jekyll-theme: minima` (or whatever it’s called). In fact, at the moment, all of the themes that come pre-installed with github pages are quite old now...

but really though, use the jekyll discussion site https://talk.jekyllrb.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can go even further and make your jekyll/minima powered site respect users theme preference
https://alexander-taran.github.io/2022/06/08/adopting-dark-theme-in-jekyll-blog.html

Comment: It seems this can be achieved with minima 3 using `minima:  
  skin: auto`. <-- hard to do multi-line yaml in a one-line comment.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum useful info from my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78095155/5874274

You can set the Minima theme to a dark skin (or one that adapts to the system setting). This is not supported by the version of the minima theme (2.5.1) used on github-pages currently but is available in the (as yet - 2024) unreleased minima 3.

```
# In _config.yml
# theme: minima
remote_theme: jekyll/minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-remote-theme
minima:
  skin: dark # or auto if you want it to switch with your system settings.
```

```html
<!-- in 404.html -->
---
permalink: /404.html
layout: base 
---
<!-- Rest of the file here -->
```